CC-CE BJT midterm question for finding High frequency
[
[

Iam stuck with this high frequency question as you can see, I was confused why the resistor "ro1" was placed that way right above the "Cpie2" ? cz from what I know it should between collector and emitter. Second question is why is "Cu" non existent for the first transistor the common collector why is that ?
Apologies if iam asking dumb questions it's cz my electrical base is weak unfortunately. Thank you for any explanation highly appreciated
Edit : I added the main diagram as requested apologies for that I thought that would be enough

There's virtually no context with these answers for whatever questions that were assigned to them. For instance, can we assume that these circuits follow the typical equivalent circuit for such CE/CS topology?

It would be very useful to add the complete bias circuit and not just the equivalent one centered in the frequency band.

As for your question about \$C_{\pi 2}\$.  \$C_{\pi 2}\$ is a \$Q_2\$ base-emitter capacitance. And this is why it is connected in parallel with \$R_3\$.
Also, \$Q_1\$ is an emitter follower hence, \$r_{o1}\$ will be connected between the emitter and AC GND. In the emitter follower the \$Q_1\$ collector is at AC GND.
We ignore \$C_{\mu1}\$ because in the case of an emitter follower, the \$C_{\mu1}\$ capacitance is much smaller compared to \$C_{\pi 2}\$ (\$C_{in} = C_{\pi 1} + C_{\mu 1}\$). Thas we can ignore it.
